# Android animate AlertDialog to a position on screen

Tags: android, animation, android-alertdialog

I have an **AlertDialog** which I would like to animate from above.It should be animated in such a way that by the time the animation is finished the **top** position of the **AlertDialog** should be of the same position as the **top** of the Toolbar like the image below. Or could you tell me how it was achieved in the image. Need your help!!

**Before Dialog animation** :

[image]

**After Dialog Animation** :

[image]

AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Animation Dialog");
                builder.setMessage("type");
                builder.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimations;
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: can you please share a link to animation or video.

Comment: It is Uber eats app.I have no link.I took screen shots.I want a translate animation.But I want to make the top of alertdialog rest on top of toolbar by the time is done.In the app it is animated from off screen from above

Comment: can you please share application link.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab.eats